# ASP Error - Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e07'

Tags: database, asp-classic, jet

im having trouble with a registration form connecting to a database and storing the data, below is the error im getting.

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e07'
>
> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
>
> /mus0280/coursework2/storefuncs.asp, line 330

This is the code snipet, i have have checked if the data types are the same in the database and the whole website.

```
' Add New User to Database
 sqlString = "INSERT INTO users ( " &_
  "user_username, " &_
  "user_password, " &_
  "user_email," &_
  "user_address, " &_
  "user_city," &_
  "user_postcode," &_
  "user_cardnumber, " &_
  "user_cardtype, " &_
  "user_cardexpiremonth," &_
  "user_cardexpireyear," &_
  "user_cardname," &_
  "user_HTML" &_
  ") VALUES ( " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( newusername ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( newpassword ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( email ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( address ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( city ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( postcode ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( cardnumber ) & "', " &_
  " '" & cardtype & "', " &_
  " '" & cardexpiremonth & "', " &_
  " '" & cardexpireyear & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( cardname ) & "', " &_
  " "  & html & " " &_
  ")"

Con.Execute sqlString
```

- this is line 330

Comment: can you print out the string so we can see it's final outcome ?

Comment: hi sorry for the unedited code, new here, anyway i figured out that the problem was with the write permissions on the folder.

Comment: Wow, what an obtuse error message for that problem eh?

Comment: @mussi89 please explain your fix as an answer so that people who find this from Google are able to easily see the fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
' Try with include single Quote's before and After Html in values (

' Add New User to Database
 sqlString = "INSERT INTO users ( " &_
  "user_username, " &_
  "user_password, " &_
  "user_email," &_
  "user_address, " &_
  "user_city," &_
  "user_postcode," &_
  "user_cardnumber, " &_
  "user_cardtype, " &_
  "user_cardexpiremonth," &_
  "user_cardexpireyear," &_
  "user_cardname," &_
  "user_HTML" &_
  ") VALUES ( " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( newusername ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( newpassword ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( email ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( address ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( city ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( postcode ) & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( cardnumber ) & "', " &_
  " '" & cardtype & "', " &_
  " '" & cardexpiremonth & "', " &_
  " '" & cardexpireyear & "', " &_
  " '" & fixQuotes( cardname ) & "', " &_
  " '"  & html & "' " &_
  ")"

Con.Execute sqlString
```